# How to implement backtracking to print the items taken in knapsack(repetition of items allowed)?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, backtracking, knapsack-problem

**I have this list of lists:**

```
[['0', 'Cool Blue Marella Jug', '33', '15'],
 ['1', 'Weight Loss Pack', '55', '16'],
 ['2', 'Natural Black Vogue Lashes', '10', '6'],
 ['3', 'Paris Age Perfect Intense Nutrition Serum', '45', '22']​
  ...]
```

- The first number is the product id,
- The second number (55,10,...) is the price and
- The third number (16,6...)is the profit.

Using my code below, if I enter a price limit I should get the highest profit by best combinations of items(items can be sold more than once).

**This is my code:**

```
def dp_pricelimit(product_list, price_limit):
    #to store results
    chosenProduct=[0]*(price_limit+1)
    memo=[0]*(price_limit+1)
    memo[0]=0
    for price in range(1, price_limit+1):
        for item in product_list:#go through the items
            if item[2]<=price:
                balance=price-item[2]
                profit=item[3] + memo[balance]
                if profit>memo[price]:#if found new optimal
                    memo[price]=profit
                    chosenProduct[price]=item[0]

    return memo[price_limit],chosenProduct
```

Now I need to modify this so that it also returns a list, `chosenProduct`, representing the chosen product ID to be sold.

**E.g.** ​If products cool blue marella jug were chosen twice and weight loss pack chosen once the list should be ,chosenProduct=[0,0,1]

I tried storing the product chosen in a list whenever I found a new optimum but it stores every optimum it finds from value 1 to price_limit. I want it to store ONLY the latest product chosen and use backtracking from there to list all product chosen that make up the profit. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Your posted code dies when it tries to compare int and string types.  After I fixed that, I found that it chooses only one item, regardless of the price.  I think your next step is to work through a tutorial on recursion and backtracking, so you are finding a valid answer.  *Then* you can worry about tracking the shopping list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def dp_pricelimit(product_list, price_limit):
    #to store results
    chosenProduct=[None]*(price_limit+1)
    memo=[0]*(price_limit+1)
    memo[0]=0
    for price in range(1, price_limit+1):
        for item in product_list:#go through the items
            if item[2]<=price:
                balance=price-item[2]

                profit=item[3] + memo[balance]
                if profit>memo[price]:#if found new optimal
                    memo[price]=profit
                    chosenProduct[price]=item[0]

    #use list to store list of item
    items = []
    #set i, the current price, to max price
    i = price_limit

    #while i is not a negative price
    while i >= 0:
        if chosenProduct[i] == None:
            break
        #append the item that was last added to make the optimal profit at price i.
        items.append(chosenProduct[i])
        #then jump back to before we added this item by decrementing the i, the current price, by the price of the last item that was added.
        i-=product_list[items[-1]][2]




    return memo[price_limit],items


print(dp_pricelimit([[0, 'Cool Blue Marella Jug', 33, 15],[1, 'Weight Loss Pack', 55, 16], [2, 'Natural Black Vogue Lashes', 10, 2], [3, 'Paris Age Perfect Intense Nutrition Serum', 45, 22]],88))
```

Basically, use the chosenproduct array to iterate backwards. The last item added to create the optimal; its cost can be subtracted to get the optimal value at the price before it was added. Then at the next price we have the last item added to get that current price inside the chosenproduct array. Good luck ;)

Comment: Also you might want to change profit variable to revenue.

Comment: Okayy thanks but I was just wondering why do we need [2] at i-=product_list[items[-1]][2]?I tried without it and unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'int' and 'list'?Does [2] mean the price?

Comment: so the [2] is the index of the price for that particaular item. So product_list[items[-1]] represents an item and product_list[items[-1]][2] is that item's price. also items[-1] represents the last element(also the last element appended) in the items array(which is a list of item IDs) and we use product_list as the lookup table for the rest of the item's info given the item's ID number.